# Summarize and Include Column Value

Tags: kql, azure-data-explorer

I'm new to KQL and thought going through the [Kusto Detective Agency](https://detective.kusto.io/) training would help. Being so new I'm stuck on the first question and can't figure out how to get past a certain point. I'm not even sure the correct terminology for my question but I've gotten to this point

```
DetectiveCases
| where EventType == 'CaseOpened'
| project CaseOpened = Timestamp, CaseId, Bounty = toreal(Properties.Bounty)
| join kind=innerunique 
    (
    DetectiveCases
    | where EventType == 'CaseSolved'
    | summarize FirstClosed=min(Timestamp) by CaseId)
    //| summarize FirstClosed=min(Timestamp) by CaseId, DetectiveId)
    on CaseId
```

That gets me a table with unique CaseId's, their Bounty and the date of the first closed case. I need to find the detective who made the most bounty and this is where I'm stuck, I can't figure out how to include the DetectiveId for only the first closed case. If I use the commented out line instead of the one above it then I get duplicate CaseId's for every Detective that solved the case. Only the first Detective that solves a case gets the bounty.

I need the detective included because then I believe I can add this to get the query to get total bounties for each detective and find the answer.

```
| summarize TotalBounty=sum(Bounty) by DetectiveId
| sort by TotalBounty desc
```

How do I include the DetectiveId, so that I can use it after the join, but only for the first solved case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is a game, and I don't want to ruin your fun I won't tell you the answer :)

You should look into [arg_min](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/arg-min-aggfunction) and [arg_max](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/arg-max-aggfunction) which directly answers your original question about getting the value of a different column than the one being maximized (or minimized).

Copying the example from the docs:

```
StormEvents 
| summarize arg_max(BeginLat, BeginLocation) by State
```

This gives you the `BeginLocation` of the maxium `BeginLat` by `State` (the example is somewhat confusing but you get the point...)

Also a small tip: use `let` (see [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/letstatement)) to better separate logic and prevent long, nested queries.

Per your example,

```
let CaseBounties = DetectiveCases
| where EventType == 'CaseOpened'
| extend Bounty = toreal(Properties.Bounty)
| project CaseId, Bounty;
DetectiveCases
| where EventType == 'CaseSolved'
| summarize FirstClosed=min(Timestamp) by CaseId)
| join CaseBounties on CaseId
...
```

Comment: Appreciate you not just giving an answer. That little hint you gave was all I needed to solve the problem and your tip will be useful in the future. Thanks for the help!